# Dynamically Populating n-D Dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, dynamic

Considering a Kindle that is white/black, with or without 3G, with or without special offers:

```
Color:  White
Connectivity:   Wi-Fi + Free 3G
Offer Type: With Special Offers
$127.49
```

Or a light switch that is white or almond, 1 pack or 10 pack:

```
Color:  White
Size:   1 Pack
$10.00
```

I want to store the prices for the various options of various products.  For the switch, it would look something like:

```
product = {
   'Color':
      {'White':
          {'Size':
              {'1 Pack':
                    {'Price': '10.0'}
            },
              {'10 Pack':
                    {'Price': '100.0'}
            }
         },
       'Almond':
          {'Size':
              {'1 Pack':
                    {'Price': '10.0'}
            },
              {'10 Pack':
                    {'Price': '100.0'}
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

What is the best way to dynamically populate a dictionary of values by option for a variable number of options?  Or other solutions that ideally do not require non-default libraries.  So far my best guess is a bunch of if-statements to handle each possible length...

```
product = {}
if len(options) == 3:
   product.update({options[0]:{}})
   product[options[0]].update({options[1]:{}})
   product[options[0]][options[1]].update({options[2]:{'Price':price}})
...
```

Note:  I understand that the 'Price' key is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Found something that was close enough to what I needed.  The code below may not work exactly, but it's pretty close to what I have.

```
from pprint import pprint

def set_nested(dic, value, *path):
   for level in path[:-1]:
      dic = dic.setdefault(level, {})

   dic[path[-1]] = value

vals = []
for option in product_listing:
   vals.append(get_option_name(option))
set_nested(costs, price, *vals)
print costs

{'Black': {'Wi-Fi + Free 3G': {'With Special Offers': 101.0,
                               'Without Special Offers': 209.99},
           'Wi-Fi Only': {'With Special Offers': 100.0,
                          'Without Special Offers': 100.0}},
 'White': {'Wi-Fi + Free 3G': {'With Special Offers': 127.49,
                               'Without Special Offers': 209.99},
           'Wi-Fi Only': {'With Special Offers': 100.0,
                          'Without Special Offers': 139.99}}}
```